# WSO2 ESB: Incoming Message Interception

Tags: wso2, interception, wso2-esb

**How to intercept all incoming message of ESB?**

I want to process all message that ESB receiving. can I do this work using handler and module in ESB?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to intercept all messages write an axis2handler and keep that in the inflow..